# Is there JQuery only (without JQuery UI) tag-it like plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tagging, anytime

I want a JQuery plugin (No JQuery UI dependancy) which is similar in functionality to tag-it plugin. i.e. it should allow user to add new tags, show autocomplete dialog, show tags in box with close button.

Main reason I don't want to use JQuery UI is because it [anyeim plugin](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) is causing problems with JQuery UI. I have looked at the issues given for AnyTime with JQuery UI but still it does not look good. I would also like to know if someone has used AnyTime with JQuery UI.

Comment: from what I see AnyTime **IS** using jquery ui, or at least parts of it's css, maybe there's some conflict due to naming?

Comment: It turns out my main question is still valid but the reason why I need a jquery only tagging plugin is not. The reason is project owner does not want to use JQuery UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as the original question still stands unanswered, this seems to be what you're after...

https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-tagit

Answer (score 3):

Any+Time(TM) should not cause any problems with jQueryUI. Please explain specifically what problem you are having, or use the contact link on the plugin page to reach me directly.

Comment: It turns out the problem I was seeing with AnyTime was not specificaly a problem of Any+Time(TM) but was problem with custom styles used with Any+Time(TM). I did not investigate further as I was told not to use JQuery UI on any of the pages.

Comment: My original question still stands. I still need a JQuery only AutoComplete+Tagging solution. And thanks for answering the question.

Comment: Any+Time(TM) does not require jQuery UI, it only honors the styles defined by jQuery UI if they have been specified.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a most recent alternative (or I would say, more 'github community points') compared to Dr.Congo's answer, you can try [tokeninput](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that's perfect! Was a little hard to find the allowFreeTagging option because it's not listed in the docs I didn't expected it already built-in :D

Would be nice to have a callback like onNoResults or beforeFreeTaggingAdd so that I could place a lable like "press enter to create new tag" :)